# Differentiability of the function defiend by the integral and $W^{1,1}$ space

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Under what conditions on $f$ the function $g(r)=\int_{B_{r}(x)}u(y)dy$ is differentiable with respect to $r.$ Moreover, under what conditions on $f,$ the function $g\in W^{1,1}(0,2),$ where $W^{1,1}$ is the soblev space.

Comment: I think it will be $\int_{B_r(x)} f(y) dy$.

Comment: Hint: Introduce polar coordinates.

Comment: Hint: use coarea formula (and integrate on spheres $\partial B_r(x)$). Can you make the questions more precise? What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Sure, I want to know that under what conditions on $f,$ the function $g$ defined by integral is in $W^{1,1}(0,\infity).$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac{d}{dr} \big( \int_{B_r(x)} f\,dx\Big) = \int_{\partial B_r(x)} f dS$, whenever $f$ is continuous and integrable.